# DiagnosticAnalyzer for Roslyn that guards against catch-all exception clauses

Tags: c#, roslyn

Dabbling around with Roslyn and made a small analyzer just now. This one will show a warning in Visual Studio when you have a try-catch statement that only has a `catch(Exception e)`.

I realize the working code (`AnalyzeNode`) is rather small, but I'm looking for feedback on best-practices (insofar there are already best practices established) and general remarks on scenarios that I might have overlooked.

I have also been looking for a way to unit test this, but haven't come up with a good solution yet. Is there an elegant way to test these analyzers instead of looking over them by hand? Or perhaps an API that exposes some crude methods which I could provide a wrapper for?

## Analyzer

```
[DiagnosticAnalyzer]
[ExportDiagnosticAnalyzer(DiagnosticId, LanguageNames.CSharp)]
class SingleGeneralExceptionAnalyzer : ISyntaxNodeAnalyzer<SyntaxKind>
{
    private const string DiagnosticId = "SingleGeneralException";
    private const string Description = "Verifies whether a try-catch block does not contain just a single Exception clause.";
    private const string MessageFormat = "A catch-all clause has been used.";
    private const string Category = "Exceptions";
    private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId, Description, MessageFormat, Category, DiagnosticSeverity.Warning);

    public ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics
    {
        get
        {
            return ImmutableArray.Create(Rule);
        }
    }

    public ImmutableArray<SyntaxKind> SyntaxKindsOfInterest
    {
        get
        {
            return ImmutableArray.Create(SyntaxKind.CatchClause);
        }
    }

    public void AnalyzeNode(SyntaxNode node, SemanticModel semanticModel, Action<Diagnostic> addDiagnostic, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var clause = node as CatchClauseSyntax;
        var exceptionType = clause.Declaration.Type;
        var identifier = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(exceptionType);
        var isGeneralException = identifier.Symbol.Name == typeof(Exception).Name;
        var hasMultipleClauses = clause.Parent.ChildNodes().OfType<CatchClauseSyntax>().ToList().Count > 1;

        // Less-specific exceptions can't be caught after a more general exception, or a compile error occurs
        // Therefore we don't need to look at the order of the clauses

        if (isGeneralException && !hasMultipleClauses)
        {
            addDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, clause.Declaration.GetLocation()));
        }
    }
}
```

## Testclass

```
class SingleExceptionClauseAnalyzer
{
    void SingleException_ShouldCause_Warning()
    {
        try
        {
            int x = Int32.Parse("5");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            int x = 8;
        }
    }

    void MultipleExceptions_ShouldNotCause_Warning()
    {
        try
        {
            int x = Int32.Parse("5");
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            int x = 7;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            int x = 8;
        }
    }

    void SingleException_WithFullyQualifiedName_ShouldCause_Warning()
    {
        try
        {
            int x = Int32.Parse("5");
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            int x = 8;
        }
    }

    void MultipleExceptions_WithFullyQualifiedName_ShouldNotCause_Warning()
    {
        try
        {
            int x = Int32.Parse("5");
        }
        catch (System.FormatException e)
        {
            int x = 7;
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            int x = 8;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The tests that Microsoft have developed for some of their own diagnostic analyzers can be found [here](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Src/Diagnostics/Test/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never coded a diagnostics analyzer, so I don't know if that's a possibility, but I think these:

```
private const string DiagnosticId = "SingleGeneralException";
private const string Description = "Verifies whether a try-catch block does not contain just a single Exception clause.";
private const string MessageFormat = "A catch-all clause has been used.";
private const string Category = "Exceptions";
```

Would be better off defined in a .resx file, so you can localize it - not everyone runs an English IDE, I'd try to have the the messages be shown in the same language as the stack traces.

---

In these declarations:

```
    var clause = node as CatchClauseSyntax;
    var exceptionType = clause.Declaration.Type;
    var identifier = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(exceptionType);
    var isGeneralException = identifier.Symbol.Name == typeof(Exception).Name;
    var hasMultipleClauses = clause.Parent.ChildNodes().OfType<CatchClauseSyntax>().ToList().Count > 1;
```

I think the relationships between the variables would be more obvious with some vertical whitespace:

```
    var clause = node as CatchClauseSyntax;

    var exceptionType = clause.Declaration.Type;
    var hasMultipleClauses = clause.Parent.ChildNodes()
                                          .OfType<CatchClauseSyntax>()
                                          .ToList().Count > 1;

    var identifier = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(exceptionType);
    var isGeneralException = identifier.Symbol.Name == typeof(Exception).Name;
```

I believe there's a possible execution path where the `clause` would be `null` (because of the `as` cast), in which case the next line would throw an easily avoidable `NullReferenceException`:

```
    var clause = node as CatchClauseSyntax;
    if (clause == null) return;
```

Comment: Since `CatchClause` is defined as `SyntaxKindsOfInterest`, that conversion should always succeed. Because of that, I would prefer a cast instead of `as`.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer mentions it all but missed one thing about the LINQ query mentioned above.

```
 var hasMultipleClauses = clause.Parent.ChildNodes()
                                       .OfType<CatchClauseSyntax>()
                                       .ToList().Count > 1;
```

This is trying to access the `Count` property after enumeration to `List`, so it is okay to get the result directly from a single `Count()` enumeration as mentioned below

```
 var hasMultipleClauses = clause.Parent.ChildNodes()
                                       .OfType<CatchClauseSyntax>()
                                       .Count() > 1;
```

Comment: Better yet, use .Any() instead of checking the Count() > 1

Comment: @Bryan `.Any()` is equivalent to `> 0`, not `> 1`.

Comment: Oops...you are right. Good catch.

Comment: `.Skip(1).Any()` would be equivalent to `> 1` but would not require iterating over the list.